# Yocto not (Skips) populating target openssl binaries in rootfs

Tags: openssl, yocto, openembedded

I am trying to add openssl_3.0.1 to my build. But when I bitbake openssl the binaries are build and installed in the tmp/**/image directory for eg: in the "/usr/bin". But when I build the whole system core image it doesn't get installed in the rootfs.

What might be the reason? I have tried install_append method to tell the build system to install this binaries specifically.

The following is my recipie

```
SUMMARY = "Secure Socket Layer"
DESCRIPTION = "Secure Socket Layer (SSL) binary and related cryptographic tools."
HOMEPAGE = "http://www.openssl.org/"
BUGTRACKER = "http://www.openssl.org/news/vulnerabilities.html"
SECTION = "libs/network"

LICENSE = "Apache-2.0"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE.txt;md5=c75985e733726beaba57bc5253e96d04"

SRC_URI = "http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-${PV}.tar.gz \
           file://run-ptest \
           file://0001-buildinfo-strip-sysroot-and-debug-prefix-map-from-co.patch \
           file://afalg.patch \
           file://0001-Configure-do-not-tweak-mips-cflags.patch \
           file://armv8-32bit.patch \
           file://0001-Fix-EVP_PKEY_CTX_get_rsa_pss_saltlen-no.patch \
           "

SRC_URI_append_class-nativesdk = " \
           file://environment.d-openssl.sh \
           "

SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "59eedfcb46c25214c9bd37ed6078297b4df01d012267fe9e9eee31f61bc70536"

inherit lib_package multilib_header multilib_script ptest perlnative
MULTILIB_SCRIPTS = "${PN}-bin:${bindir}/c_rehash"

PACKAGECONFIG ?= ""
PACKAGECONFIG_class-native = ""
PACKAGECONFIG_class-nativesdk = ""

PACKAGECONFIG[cryptodev-linux] = "-DHAVE_CRYPTODEV -DUSE_CRYPTODEV_DIGESTS,-UHAVE_CRYPTODEV,cryptodev-linux"
PACKAGECONFIG[no-tls1] = "no-tls1"
PACKAGECONFIG[no-tls1_1] = "no-tls1_1"

B = "${WORKDIR}/build"
do_configure[cleandirs] = "${B}"

#| ./libcrypto.so: undefined reference to `getcontext'
#| ./libcrypto.so: undefined reference to `setcontext'
#| ./libcrypto.so: undefined reference to `makecontext'
EXTRA_OECONF_append_libc-musl = " no-async"
EXTRA_OECONF_append_libc-musl_powerpc64 = " no-asm"

# adding devrandom prevents openssl from using getrandom() which is not available on older glibc versions
# (native versions can be built with newer glibc, but then relocated onto a system with older glibc)
EXTRA_OECONF_class-native = "--with-rand-seed=os,devrandom"
EXTRA_OECONF_class-nativesdk = "--with-rand-seed=os,devrandom"

# Relying on hardcoded built-in paths causes openssl-native to not be relocateable from sstate.
CFLAGS_append_class-native = " -DOPENSSLDIR=/not/builtin -DENGINESDIR=/not/builtin"
CFLAGS_append_class-nativesdk = " -DOPENSSLDIR=/not/builtin -DENGINESDIR=/not/builtin"

# This allows disabling deprecated or undesirable crypto algorithms.
# The default is to trust upstream choices.
DEPRECATED_CRYPTO_FLAGS ?= ""

do_configure () {
    os=${HOST_OS}
    case $os in
    linux-gnueabi |\
    linux-gnuspe |\
    linux-musleabi |\
    linux-muslspe |\
    linux-musl )
        os=linux
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
    esac
    target="$os-${HOST_ARCH}"
    case $target in
    linux-arc)
        target=linux-latomic
        ;;
    linux-arm*)
        target=linux-armv4
        ;;
    linux-aarch64*)
        target=linux-aarch64
        ;;
    linux-i?86 | linux-viac3)
        target=linux-x86
        ;;
    linux-gnux32-x86_64 | linux-muslx32-x86_64 )
        target=linux-x32
        ;;
    linux-gnu64-x86_64)
        target=linux-x86_64
        ;;
    linux-mips | linux-mipsel)
        # specifying TARGET_CC_ARCH prevents openssl from (incorrectly) adding target architecture flags
        target="linux-mips32 ${TARGET_CC_ARCH}"
        ;;
    linux-gnun32-mips*)
        target=linux-mips64
        ;;
    linux-*-mips64 | linux-mips64 | linux-*-mips64el | linux-mips64el)
        target=linux64-mips64
        ;;
    linux-microblaze* | linux-nios2* | linux-sh3 | linux-sh4 | linux-arc*)
        target=linux-generic32
        ;;
    linux-powerpc)
        target=linux-ppc
        ;;
    linux-powerpc64)
        target=linux-ppc64
        ;;
    linux-powerpc64le)
        target=linux-ppc64le
        ;;
    linux-riscv32)
        target=linux-generic32
        ;;
    linux-riscv64)
        target=linux-generic64
        ;;
    linux-sparc | linux-supersparc)
        target=linux-sparcv9
        ;;
    mingw32-x86_64)
        target=mingw64
        ;;
    esac

    useprefix=${prefix}
    if [ "x$useprefix" = "x" ]; then
        useprefix=/
    fi
    # WARNING: do not set compiler/linker flags (-I/-D etc.) in EXTRA_OECONF, as they will fully replace the
    # environment variables set by bitbake. Adjust the environment variables instead.
    HASHBANGPERL="/usr/bin/env perl" PERL=perl PERL5LIB="${S}/external/perl/Text-Template-1.46/lib/" \
    perl ${S}/Configure ${EXTRA_OECONF} ${PACKAGECONFIG_CONFARGS} ${DEPRECATED_CRYPTO_FLAGS} --prefix=$useprefix --openssldir=${libdir}/ssl-3 --libdir=${libdir} $target
    perl ${B}/configdata.pm --dump
}

do_install () {
    oe_runmake DESTDIR="${D}" MANDIR="${mandir}" MANSUFFIX=ssl install

    oe_libinstall -so libcrypto ${D}${libdir}
    oe_libinstall -so libssl ${D}${libdir}
    oe_libinstall -so libssl.so.3 ${D}${libdir}
    

    oe_multilib_header openssl/opensslconf.h
    oe_multilib_header openssl/configuration.h

    # Create SSL structure for packages such as ca-certificates which
    # contain hard-coded paths to /etc/ssl. Debian does the same.
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/ssl
    mv ${D}${libdir}/ssl-3/certs \
       ${D}${libdir}/ssl-3/private \
       ${D}${libdir}/ssl-3/openssl.cnf \
       ${D}${sysconfdir}/ssl/

    # Although absolute symlinks would be OK for the target, they become
    # invalid if native or nativesdk are relocated from sstate.
    ln -sf ${@oe.path.relative('${libdir}/ssl-3', '${sysconfdir}/ssl/certs')} ${D}${libdir}/ssl-3/certs
    ln -sf ${@oe.path.relative('${libdir}/ssl-3', '${sysconfdir}/ssl/private')} ${D}${libdir}/ssl-3/private
    ln -sf ${@oe.path.relative('${libdir}/ssl-3', '${sysconfdir}/ssl/openssl.cnf')} ${D}${libdir}/ssl-3/openssl.cnf
}

do_install_append_class-native () {
    create_wrapper ${D}${bindir}/openssl \
        OPENSSL_CONF=${libdir}/ssl-3/openssl.cnf \
        SSL_CERT_DIR=${libdir}/ssl-3/certs \
        SSL_CERT_FILE=${libdir}/ssl-3/cert.pem \
        OPENSSL_ENGINES=${libdir}/engines-3
}

do_install_append_class-nativesdk () {
    mkdir -p ${D}${SDKPATHNATIVE}/environment-setup.d
    install -m 644 ${WORKDIR}/environment.d-openssl.sh ${D}${SDKPATHNATIVE}/environment-setup.d/openssl.sh
    sed 's|/usr/lib/ssl/|/usr/lib/ssl-3/|g' -i ${D}${SDKPATHNATIVE}/environment-setup.d/openssl.sh
}

PTEST_BUILD_HOST_FILES += "configdata.pm"
PTEST_BUILD_HOST_PATTERN = "perl_version ="
do_install_ptest () {
    install -d ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/test
    install -m755 ${B}/test/p_test.so ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/test
    install -m755 ${B}/test/provider_internal_test.cnf ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/test

    # Prune the build tree
    rm -f ${B}/fuzz/*.* ${B}/test/*.*

    cp ${S}/Configure ${B}/configdata.pm ${D}${PTEST_PATH}
    sed 's|${S}|${PTEST_PATH}|g' -i ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/configdata.pm
    cp -r ${S}/external ${B}/test ${S}/test ${B}/fuzz ${S}/util ${B}/util ${D}${PTEST_PATH}

    # For test_shlibload
    ln -s ${libdir}/libcrypto.so.1.1 ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/
    ln -s ${libdir}/libssl.so.1.1 ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/

    install -d ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/apps
    ln -s ${bindir}/openssl ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/apps
    install -m644 ${S}/apps/*.pem ${S}/apps/*.srl ${S}/apps/openssl.cnf ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/apps
    install -m755 ${B}/apps/CA.pl ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/apps

    install -d ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/engines
    install -m755 ${B}/engines/ossltest.so ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/engines
    install -m755 ${B}/engines/loader_attic.so ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/engines

    install -d ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/providers
    install -m755 ${B}/providers/legacy.so ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/providers

        install -d ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/Configurations
        cp -rf ${S}/Configurations/* ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/Configurations/

        # seems to be needed with perl 5.32.1
        install -d ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/util/perl/recipes
        cp ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/test/recipes/tconversion.pl ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/util/perl/recipes/

    sed 's|${S}|${PTEST_PATH}|g' -i ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/util/wrap.pl

}

# Add the openssl.cnf file to the openssl-conf package. Make the libcrypto
# package RRECOMMENDS on this package. This will enable the configuration
# file to be installed for both the openssl-bin package and the libcrypto
# package since the openssl-bin package depends on the libcrypto package.

PACKAGES =+ "libcrypto libssl openssl-conf ${PN}-engines ${PN}-misc"

FILES_libcrypto = "${libdir}/libcrypto${SOLIBS}"
FILES_libssl = "${libdir}/libssl${SOLIBS}"
FILES_openssl-conf = "${sysconfdir}/ssl/openssl.cnf \
                      ${libdir}/ssl-3/openssl.cnf* \
                      "
FILES_${PN}-engines = "${libdir}/engines-3"
# ${prefix} comes from what we pass into --prefix at configure time (which is used for INSTALLTOP)
FILES_${PN}-engines_append_mingw32_class-nativesdk = " ${prefix}${libdir}/engines-3"
FILES_${PN}-misc = "${libdir}/ssl-3/misc ${bindir}/c_rehash"
#FILES_${PN} =+ "${libdir}/ssl-3/* ${libdir}/ossl-modules/"
FILES_${PN} =+ "${libdir}/* ${bindir}/*"
FILES_${PN}_append_class-nativesdk = " ${SDKPATHNATIVE}/environment-setup.d/openssl.sh"

CONFFILES_openssl-conf = "${sysconfdir}/ssl/openssl.cnf"

RRECOMMENDS_libcrypto += "openssl-conf"
RDEPENDS_${PN}-misc = "perl"
RDEPENDS_${PN}-ptest += "openssl-bin perl perl-modules bash"

RDEPENDS_${PN}-bin += "openssl-conf"

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"

CVE_PRODUCT = "openssl:openssl"

CVE_VERSION_SUFFIX = "alphabetical"

# Only affects OpenSSL >= 1.1.1 in combination with Apache < 2.4.37
```

I have also added the openssl in IMAGE_INSTALL

Comment: did you add it to `IMAGE_INSTALL`?

Comment: Yes I already added openssl in the IMAGE_INSTALL but it doesn't work!